# Reapply actions/action history with Redux

Tags: redux

I'm using Redux (with React) to handle state in my application. I have the following scenario:

1. Load a list of items
2. Apply transform(s) to a list (arbitrary number of transforms)
3. Reduce displayed items in list
4. Increase displayed items in list

At step 4: How do I best achieve to again increase displayed items, with transforms from step 1 still applied/reapplied?

An example:

1. Load list with 50 items
2. Uppercase items
3. Filter items to display items with less than 4 chars (=> results in
   30 items)
4. Apply filter again to display items with less than 10 chars (=> should result in 50 items with all still uppercased)

Comment: Best I can come up with myself is extending every list item, as such (with example as upper-cased and max 5 chars):
```[{ value: 'text', displayValue: 'TEXT', filtered: false }, { value: 'another text', displayValue: 'ANOTHER TEXT', filtered: true }]```

This is a simple solution to the problem, but I want to know what the idiomatic way would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description, the only *actual* state that should be kept in the store is the initial data and the information about current filters. For example, your state shape might look like:

```
{
  items: ['April', 'Jake', 'Mary', 'Zooey', 'Dan'],
  filters: {
    isUppercase: false,
    maxLength: 10
  }
}
```

As you change the data, the `items` reducer would handle adding and deleting items. As you change the filters, the `filter` reducer would record the new filter setting.

Now comes the important part. **The actual filtering happens when the data is selected for the components.**

We suggest to store the minimal possible state in Redux. In this case the list itself and the information about the filters *is* the minimal possible state. **The current list with the filters applied can always be calculated from the state, so it shouldn’t be in the state**.

Instead, you can write a pure function that selects the data according to the current state:

```
function filterItems(items, filters) {
  return items.filter(item => {
    // return true or false depending on your logic
  })
}
```

Now, if you use React, you can call it in your `render()` method:

```
var filteredItems = filterItems(this.props.items, this.props.filters)
```

You might find that re-computing this on every render can be inefficient. Thankfully, the solution is simple: [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). Make sure the derived data is only recalculated when the inputs change. [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) is a tiny library that lets you do that, and it is often used together with Redux.

You can find more information about this topic with some examples in the official [Computing Derived Data](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html) recipe on Redux website, and in the [Reselect README](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect).